# #JAVA - Programme calculates the sum of numbers from 1 to 10,000 (including 1 and 10,000) omitting numbers numbers whose hundred digit is 2 or 3

Tags: java, numbers

1. Hello, this is my code. I need to print number 1 to 10.000. But every number with 200 to 399 need to be hide. Exemple : 1269, 1325, 1234...

`````
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int nombre = 0;
        while (nombre < 10000) {
            nombre++;

            if (nombre%200 == 0 || nombre - nombre%399 == 0)  {
                System.out.println("Le nombre est entre 100 - 300");
            }
            else if (nombre % 3 ==0) {
                System.out.println("Le nombre est divisible par 3 ");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(nombre);
            }
        }
    }
}````

// Thanks for the help !`
`````

Comment: `every number with 200 to 399 need to be hid` ... can you explain what this means?

Comment: The numbers containing number within the range 200-399, should not be printed right?

Comment: yes exactly, every number like 1200-1399 should be hide. 1200-1399, 2200-2399, 3200-3399.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use modulus to find the last 3 digits and then check that with your condition.

```
   public printNum() {
        int num = 0;
        while (num < 10000) {
            num++;
            int last3Digits = num % 1000;
            if (!(last3Digits >= 200 || last3Digits <= 399)){
                System.out.println(num);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this solves it

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time ! I tryed this solution and it doesn't seem to work, i understand the idea behind this and i don't know why when i run the code it only print everynumber 1 too 10.000

Comment: I found the error ! You gave me the right answer but you miss the part ||. Because every number can be superior at 200 and inferior at 399. So i just changed the || FOR && AND IT WORKED ! Thanks you for your time, without you i could'n found !

Comment: Great to hear that. Glad could help